# Ignoring Javadoc errors in dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have a [Java project](https://github.com/Choonster-Minecraft-Mods/TestMod3/tree/1.16.x) built with Gradle (it's a Minecraft Forge mod). It depends on another project called [HWYLA](https://github.com/TehNut/HWYLA), which has an API JAR containing both compiled classes and their source code. Unfortunately there seem to be some Javadoc errors in this code, which is preventing the generation of Javadoc for my own code.

The Gradle output looks like this (from [this](https://github.com/Choonster-Minecraft-Mods/TestMod3/runs/1271533552) CI run):

```
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :makeLibraryMetas UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar
> Task :downloadMcpConfig
> Task :extractSrg
> Task :createMcpToSrg
> Task :reobfJar
/home/runner/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/deobf_dependencies/mcp/mobius/waila/Hwyla/1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2/Hwyla-1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2-api.jar(mcp/mobius/waila/api/IComponentProvider.java):56: error: invalid end tag: </br>

     * Callback used to add lines to one of the three sections of the tooltip (Head, Body, Tail).</br>
                                                                                                 ^
/home/runner/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/deobf_dependencies/mcp/mobius/waila/Hwyla/1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2/Hwyla-1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2-api.jar(mcp/mobius/waila/api/IComponentProvider.java):57: error: invalid end tag: </br>
     * Will only be called if the implementing class is registered via {@link IRegistrar#registerComponentProvider(IComponentProvider, TooltipPosition, Class)}.</br>
> Task :javadoc
                                                                                                                                                                ^
/home/runner/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/deobf_dependencies/mcp/mobius/waila/Hwyla/1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2/Hwyla-1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2-api.jar(mcp/mobius/waila/api/IComponentProvider.java):58: error: invalid end tag: </br>
     * You are supposed to always return the modified input tooltip.</br>
                                                                    ^
/home/runner/.gradle/caches/forge_gradle/deobf_dependencies/mcp/mobius/waila/Hwyla/1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2/Hwyla-1.10.11-B78_1.16.2_mapped_snapshot_20200916-1.16.2-api.jar(mcp/mobius/waila/api/RenderableTextComponent.java):5: error: package mcp.mobius.waila.api.impl does not exist
import mcp.mobius.waila.api.impl.WailaRegistrar;
                                ^
4 errors

> Task :javadoc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':javadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): '/home/runner/work/TestMod3/TestMod3/build/tmp/javadoc/javadoc.options'
```

How can I tell Gradle/Javadoc to ignore these errors and just generate the documentation for my own code? I could probably turn off doclint, but I'd rather avoid doing that.

I've tried inspecting the `tasks.javadoc.source` property and adding an exclude filter to the task; but these only contain the paths of my own code, not the HWYLA JAR or source files.

Comment: You can correct the errors. Just change `</br>` to `<br/>` or just `<br>`.

Comment: @Abra The errors aren't in my code, they're in a dependency.